# Nested loop for VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, loops, nested-loops

In VB.NET I want to print numbers as such that everytime inner loop finishes till 4 The outer loop should increase by 1 accordingly. 
like:

```
y:0
Z:0
Z:1
Z:2
Z:3
Z:4


y:0
y:1
Z:0
Z:1
Z:2
Z:3
Z:4

y:0
y:1
y:2
Z:0
Z:1
Z:2
Z:3
Z:4
```

i need a dynamic code because Y and Z are inputs. Not even getting idea how to construct such loop.

EDIT: By the time y finishes its limit the loop should be stopped. y should not exceed z.
Any two loops only have to be used for this because at some point of time i have to compare the value of y with z and find how many duplicate values exist in y

Comment: Are you looking for something like `For outerLimit = 0 To 3` `For inner = 0 To outerLimit`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton y should always be less than Z

Comment: @AndrewMorton for example if y = 3 then Z=10 or more

Comment: @AndrewMorton As you can see z is running till its given limit. while the value of y is increasing by 1 with z. By the moment y finishes its given limit the loop should be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this in VB6. See if this helps you translate it to vb.net

```
Sub test()
Dim y As Integer
Dim y2 As Integer
Dim z As Integer

y = 5
y2 = 0

Do While y2 < 5
    y = 0
    For y = 0 To y2
        Debug.Print "y:" & y
    Next
    For z = 1 To 4
        Debug.Print "z:" & z
    Next
    y2 = y2 + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Any two loops only have to be used for this because at some point of time i have to compare the value of y with z and find how many duplicate values exist in y

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For x = 0 To 2
    For y = 0 To x
        Console.WriteLine("y:{0}", y)
    Next
    For z = 0 To 4
        Console.WriteLine("Z:{0}", z)
    Next
    For i = 1 To 2 - x
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
Next
```

It gives me this:

```
y:0
Z:0
Z:1
Z:2
Z:3
Z:4


y:0
y:1
Z:0
Z:1
Z:2
Z:3
Z:4

y:0
y:1
y:2
Z:0
Z:1
Z:2
Z:3
Z:4
```

Comment: Any two loops only have to be used for this because at some point of time i have to compare the value of y with z and find how many duplicate values exist in y

Comment: @SatishGupta - You need to make this clearer in your question. I have replicated the example output that you wanted. If there's something different then you need to make the output reflect that. I think you need at least one outer loop and two inner ones to make this work.